# Electric field of a Uniformly charged sphere with a cavity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, superposition

I have the following question:

> Consider a sphere of radius $R$, uniformly charged with a volume density $\rho$. The
>   sphere has a spherical hole of radius $R/4$ at a distance $R/2$ from the centre of the
>   sphere determine the electric field inside the hole

And despite understanding the theory around these types of questions however the solutions was not helpful in the slightest could someone walk me through this?
I know I have to use superposition and Gauss' law but that's all I have.

Comment: I am aware that it is a homework question however as stated in the question I said I had the solution but it didnt make sense to me hence I wanted someone to show me how they did it so giving them my work would defeat the objective of my question

Answer (score 3):

**HINT :**  Electric field inside a uniformly charged solid nonconducting sphere is $ \rho r/3\epsilon $ where $r$ is the radius vector with respect to Centre of sphere.

Consider a full sphere (with filled cavity) with charge density $\rho$ and another smaller sphere with charge density $-\rho$ (the cavity). By superposition it will give the sphere with a cavity.

Now write Electric field in vector form and add both vectors. You will see that electric field inside cavity will be uniform and equal to $ \rho l/3\epsilon $ where $l$ is the vector joining centre of sphere and centre of cavity.
Hope this helps!

Proof of Electric field inside uniformly charged sphere
[image]